# node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1029 throw err

Tags: angular, npm

I'm getting following Console Error.
Error : Cannot find module

Here is the full error i'm getting in console. What should I do?

```
node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1029
  throw err;
  ^

Error: Cannot find module '/home/hiranwj/list'
    at Module._resolveFilename (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1026:15)
    at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:872:27)
    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (node:internal/modules/run_main:82:12)
    at node:internal/main/run_main_module:23:47 {
  code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
}
```

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I'm new to this whole realm - so take everything here with a grain of salt - but I did just get that same message myself recently. It turned out that I was trying to access node from within the parent directory of the directory where I had actually installed node. Check that you are, in fact, in the directory where you installed node. Typing `pwd` will tell you which directory you're currently working in and typing `ls -a` will give you a comprehensive list of all the files within that directory. You want to make sure you see node_modules in the directory you are trying to use it in. At least this has been my experience. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

This error means that you did not install your package so you should install it :

> npm install hiranwj